# How to hide a title bar in CDockablePane in float state?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dock

```
virtual int GetCaptionHeight() const{ return 0; }
```

I use this can hide title bar in docking state,but when it's float,the title is present.

Answer (score 0):

The caption is drawn from the Pane only when it is not floating. Just look into the default implementation for `GetCaptionHeight`!

The pane is inside a `CPaneFrameWnd` when it is floating.

AFAIK you have to control over the outer frame window. It is created by `CreateDefaultMiniframe`. It should usually create a `CPaneFrameWnd`.

Derive your own class from the default mini frame class. (should be `CPaneFrameWnd`, but better recheck it). There is a virtual function `CPaneFrameWnd::GetCaptionRect`.

Use `SetMiniFrameRTC` in your `CDockablePane` class to set this new class frame to be used for your pane.

Comment: I do the steps above(DECLARE_DYNCREATE/IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE need to be modified to DECLARE_SERIAL/IMPLEMENT_SERIAL),and I override void CSkinPaneFrameWnd::GetCaptionRect(CRect& rectCaption) const
{
 rectCaption = CRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
but the title position is displayed with a black rect.

Comment: Hmm. Debug. Who is calling GetCaptionRect? How it is evaluated?

Comment: thank you for your answer,I find it's callled when draw capition,It's difficult for me do more research.

Comment: In my case I can't see that if the caption rect you return is empty that any drawing is done at all.